# Why this systemd service get failed?

Tags: 18.04, server, systemd, services

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04 server** I created systemd file called **socket-io.service** with the location like this

**Created Systemd Service**

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/socket-io.service


[Unit]
Description=Sellist Notification Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minion
Group=minion
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /var/www/socket.io/server.js

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**Then Enable and Start Service**

```
systemctl enable socket-io && systemctl start socket-io
```

**But the result - Failed to start**

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status socket-io
● socket-io.service - Sellist Notification Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/socket-io.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-12-19 08:00:45 UTC; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 4356 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Dec 19 08:00:44 ubuntu systemd[1]: socket-io.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Dec 19 08:00:44 ubuntu systemd[1]: socket-io.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 19 08:00:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: socket-io.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 19 08:00:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: socket-io.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 19 08:00:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Sellist Notification Service.
Dec 19 08:00:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: socket-io.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 19 08:00:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: socket-io.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 19 08:00:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Sellist Notification Service.
```

I tried to create some other Systemd services like Laravel queue that's too end up with Failed status . Please help me to solve this thanks in advanced.

Comment: What happens when you execute `/usr/bin/node /var/www/socket.io/server.js` manually? What is the output of `journalctl -xu socket-io` when the service failed?

Comment: I can manually run with the command ```node server.js```

Comment: Do you run it as `minion`?

Comment: no but will it be a matter in that case ?

Comment: Of course it will. Your Service runs the command with This uid.